# Flutter How to bring forward a item in stack with Listview Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is my widget.

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Tooltip(
              message: controller.salonModel.barberListName(index),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: primary, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Align(
                widthFactor: 0.7,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: CircularPhotoContainer(
                  width: 50,
                  photoUrl: controller.salonModel.barberListPhotos(index),
                  borderColor: index == 0 ? secondary : bGroundColor,
                  color: bGroundColor,
                  borderWidth: 4,
                  radius: 100,
                  boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                  opacity: 1,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

This is ui.
[image]

I want to bring forward my first item like this but I didn't do that.
[image]

So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `ListView.builder`  use `reverse: true,` If you like to order items on UI, you can use index as `length-index-1`

```dart
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 5,
  reverse: true, //this
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {.....
```

Test example

```dart
class ListTe extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTe({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Color> colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.pink];
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: colors.length,
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Align(
            widthFactor: 0.7,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: colors[colors.length - 1 - index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Reverse property does not giving what I want exactly. I didn't mention above sorry but my first item is special item. It is user's photo who registered first.

Comment: in that case, the first item index is `length-index-1` does it solve the issue?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand what you mean with ```length-index-1```. Should I use if else inside ```itemBuilder```?

Comment: yes, while we've reversed the list, the 1st item means index`0`  will be the last item index. try `photoUrl: controller.salonModel.barberListPhotos(itemlength-index-1)`, in your case itemLength is 2.

Comment: Oh you got me wrong I guess sir. I would like to replace first photo in front of second photo.

Comment: Sorry I am still not clear what are  you trying to archive, can point the color which one should be the 1st item and how it will be placed over ui.

Comment: Hmm. I would like to place each widget it behind the widget that came before it.

Comment: can try test example code what changes you are trying to archive?

Comment: You already solved that but I missed a part of your code. Thank you so much and Im sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It fine, glad to help you out, You can check more about [reversed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/reversed.html)